# teradataml: what are the various authentication mechanisms supported by context manager in teradataml?

Tags: python, teradata

In teradataml does create_context support ldap? What other authentication mechanisms are supported? 
How can user specify ldap server while creating context?

Answer (score 0):

```
create_context(host=None, username=None, password=None, tdsqlengine=None, temp_database_name=None, logmech=None)
    DESCRIPTION:
        Creates a connection to the Teradata Vantage using the teradatasql + teradatasqlalchemy DBAPI and dialect combination.
        Users can pass all required parameters (host, username, password) for establishing a connection to Vantage,
        or pass a sqlalchemy engine to the tdsqlengine parameter to override the default DBAPI and dialect combination.

    PARAMETERS:
        host:
            Optional Argument.
            Specifies the fully qualified domain name or IP address of the Teradata System.
            Types: str

        username:
            Optional Argument.
            Specifies the username for logging onto the Teradata Vantage.
            Types: str

        password:
            Optional Argument.
            Specifies the password required for the username.
            Types: str

        tdsqlengine:
            Optional Argument.
            Specifies Teradata Vantage sqlalchemy engine object that should be used to establish a Teradata Vantage connection.
            Types: str

        temp_database_name:
            Optional Argument.
            Specifies the temporary database name where temporary tables, views will be created.
            Types: str

        ***logmech:
            Optional Argument.
            Specifies the type of logon mechanism to establish a connection to Teradata Vantage.*** 
            ***Permitted Values: 'TD2', 'TDNEGO', 'LDAP' & 'KRB5'.***
            ***Types: str***

    RETURNS:
        A Teradata sqlalchemy engine object.

    RAISES:
        TeradataMlException

Example for using LDAP server:
con = create_context(host = 'ldap server', username='ldapuser', password = 'ldappassword', logmech='LDAP')
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can user specify ldap server while creating context?

You do not specify the LDAP server in the connection parameters. That is not possible and is not necessary.

LDAP authentication only works if your Teradata Database system has been configured on the server side to offer LDAP authentication. The LDAP server that is used is the LDAP server that the Teradata Database system is configured to use.